# Express GET returning an empty bracket

Tags: node.js, express, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to do an API using the Google Sheets API. But in my application I always get an empty array as response. These are my codes:

**index.routes.js**

```
import { Router } from "express";

const router = Router();

const funciones = require("../functions/index.functions.js");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.hbs");
});

router.post("/trabajador/agregar", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  res.send("Trabajador Agregado");
});

router.get("/trabajador/obtener", (req, res) => {
  res.send(funciones.obtenertrabajadores());
});

export default router;
```

**index.functions.js**

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets('v4');

async function obtenertrabajadores () {
  const authClient = await authorize();
  const request = {
    // ID DE LA HOJA
    spreadsheetId: 'ID',
        
    // RANGO
    range: 'C1:C',

    // UNFORMATTED_VALUE.
    valueRenderOption: 'UNFORMATTED_VALUE', 

    // SERIAL_NUMBER
    dateTimeRenderOption: 'SERIAL_NUMBER',

    auth: authClient,
  };

  try {
    const response = (await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request)).data;
    return JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

async function authorize() {
  let authClient = 'AuthKey';

  if (authClient == null) {
    throw Error('authentication failed');
  }

  return authClient;
}

module.exports = {
    obtenertrabajadores: obtenertrabajadores
};
```

If I console log the response, the code works, but when I make the GET petition to /trabajador/obtener, returns '{}'

I would like the response to be a json with the data obtained from the request to Google Sheet

I suppose it is because it is returning a promise, but how can I fix it?

Comment: First, try console logging const response. Then you will see what you are getting as a response to your request. If you are getting data, I'd recommend you to use your function as a middleware.

Comment: Sure, if I console log, I get something like this: 
GET /trabajador/obtener 200 6.267 ms - 2
[
  [ 'NOMBRE' ],
]

But I don't know how send the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use functions as middleware since they tend to repeat.

in **index.functions.js:**

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets('v4');

async function obtenertrabajadores (req, res, next) {
  const authClient = await authorize();
  const request = {
    // ID DE LA HOJA
    spreadsheetId: 'ID',
        
    // RANGO
    range: 'C1:C',

    // UNFORMATTED_VALUE.
    valueRenderOption: 'UNFORMATTED_VALUE', 

    // SERIAL_NUMBER
    dateTimeRenderOption: 'SERIAL_NUMBER',

    auth: authClient,
  };

  try {
    const response = (await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request)).data;
    req.response = response //Appending response to req so that you can catch it later
    return
    next()
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

async function authorize() {
  let authClient = 'AuthKey';

  if (authClient == null) {
    throw Error('authentication failed');
  }

  return authClient;
}

module.exports = obtenertrabajadores
```

in index.routes.js:

```
router.get("/trabajador/obtener", obtenertrabajadores, (req, res) => {
  const response = req.response
  res.json(response)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @jkalandarov mentioned, functions as middleware works fine!

I just changed some little things to make it work:

**index.routes.js**
import { Router } from "express";

```
const router = Router();

import obtenertrabajadores from "../functions/index.functions.js";

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.hbs");
});

router.post("/trabajador/agregar", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  res.send("Trabajador Agregado");
});

router.get("/trabajador/obtener", obtenertrabajadores, (req, res) => {
    const response = req.response
    res.json(response)
});

export default router;
```

**index.functions.js**

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets('v4');

async function obtenertrabajadores (req, res, next) {
  const authClient = await authorize();
  const request = {
    // ID DE LA HOJA
    spreadsheetId: 'ID',
        
    // RANGO
    range: 'C1:C',

    // UNFORMATTED_VALUE.
    valueRenderOption: 'UNFORMATTED_VALUE', 

    // SERIAL_NUMBER
    dateTimeRenderOption: 'SERIAL_NUMBER',

    auth: authClient,
  };

  try {
    const response = (await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request)).data;
    req.response = response //Appending response to req so that you can catch it later
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

async function authorize() {
  let authClient = 'AuthKey';

  if (authClient == null) {
    throw Error('authentication failed');
  }

  return authClient;
}

module.exports = obtenertrabajadores
```